# Kubernetes: how is it possible to test whether there is a node with sufficient resources before starting a job

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to test whether there is a node with sufficient resources before starting a job?

Comment: Available resources fluctuate from moment to moment. A node that had sufficient resources 100 milliseconds ago may not have sufficient resources anymore. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Better to enable autoscaling of your cluster and run the job whenever you want.

Comment: It's a self hosted k8s. We want to automatically switch to a cloud provider when our cluster runs out of resources

Comment: May I suggest you to use [metrics server](from https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server). You install it, then with `kubeclt top nodes --sort-by=[JSON_PATH]` to get the first at top, then you can add some pipes (`| grep`) to catch the value you need and perform some checks, filters.

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends on the environment you are building (from my experience).

Disk space, process power and memory can be easily tracked.

From the control plane you can install kubernetes/metrics-server and use

```
kubectl top nodes
```

for the current situation of the nodes.
Also if you have local volume provisioning via blockDevices (eq. openebs-cstore)
You can always use

```
kubectl get bd --all-namespaces
```

to see the available blockdevices or if you have cstore pools

```
kubectl get csp --all-namespaces
```

to check the allocation process and capacity on the disks.

EQ.

```
NAME                   ALLOCATED   FREE    CAPACITY   STATUS    READONLY   TYPE      AGE
cstor-disk-pool-1tgd   264K        19.9G   19.9G      Healthy   false      striped   22h
cstor-disk-pool-3cvq   393K        19.9G   19.9G      Healthy   false      striped   22h
cstor-disk-pool-coq6   254K        9.94G   9.94G      Healthy   false      striped   22h
```

In the local version these information are avaliable and useful (for me at least).

Once you check these resources if you have a deployment definition with resource claims (cpu and memory included) you can decide whether you need more or less of a specific resource.

Also you can create a test environment to freely test the deployment (with higher resources) and than decide the cluster or the node you want to use.